# Xquery to find the value of an xml element

Tags: t-sql, xquery

All,I am trying to get the value of the element **Value** when the value of  **Name** is org_id.This xml is placed in the database by an external process that i don't have control over.
There could be multiple **ParematerValue** nodes ,so i am not sure about the position of **Value** element when the **Name** is org_Id.The only guarantee is that there will be only one element **Name** with the value org_id.

Is there a way to find the value of **Value** in this scenario?

sample xml(my_xml)

```
 <ParameterValues>  
        <ParameterValue>
            <Name>car_model</Name>
            <Value>All</Value>
        </ParameterValue>
        <ParameterValue>
            <Name>debug</Name>
            <Value>0</Value>
        </ParameterValue>
        <ParameterValue>
            <Name>org_Id</Name>
            <Value>123456</Value>
        </ParameterValue>
    </ParameterValues>

My XQuery 

    select  
        my_xml.value('(/ParameterValues/ParameterValue/Value)[3]','int') as org_wk

    from 
        #test_xml 
    where
        my_xml.exist('/ParameterValues/ParameterValue/Name[text() = "org_Id"]') = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
-- sample data
CREATE TABLE #test_xml (my_xml XML);
INSERT #test_xml
VALUES
('<ParameterValues>  
            <ParameterValue>
                <Name>car_model</Name>
                <Value>All</Value>
            </ParameterValue>
            <ParameterValue>
                <Name>debug</Name>
                <Value>0</Value>
            </ParameterValue>
            <ParameterValue>
                <Name>org_Id</Name>
                <Value>123456</Value>
            </ParameterValue>
        </ParameterValues>');

-- solution    
SELECT x2.p.value('(text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') 
FROM #test_xml x1
CROSS APPLY x1.my_xml.nodes('//ParameterValue[Name="org_Id"]/Value') x2(p);
```

Comment: For anyone who is looking for a decent explanation of commonly used Xquery methods (exist(),query(),value(),node()),this is a very good one https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/the-xml-methods-in-sql-server/